# bulk_insert_mappings sync model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert

In a loop with bulk insert:

```
while condition:    
    with transaction.manager:
        mapper = inspect(Foo)
        session.bulk_insert_mappings(mapper, foo_list)
        session.commit()
```

is the insert operation async or sync?
I want to know when the loop is started for second time, the data from first loop is in db necessarily or not?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `commit()` is blocking or non-blocking is not handled by SQLAlchemy itself but by the SQL library you are using.

The great majority of current SQL libraries are blocking, but there are some that are not, so I suggest you look at your SQL library's documentation.

Comment: by SQL library, you mean DBMS? I'm using SQL Server. You mean blocking or non-blocking is handled by SQL Server?